# "It ... how is" vs "It ... how it is"

Tags: grammar, subjects

Is correct to say "how is" in a phrase which the subject was mentioned before?

> It also showed me how is to ...

or

> It also showed me how it is to ...

With "was" I would put the "it" but that is automatic for me. I don't know if that is incorrect, is it?

Comment: Including the "it" is usually more correct: "show me how **it** is"...

Comment: But once the subject was mentioned before, does it still necessary to mention it again? Is it not like a duplication or the second "it" is for the following phrase?

Comment: "It also showed me how it is to be a student." goes with the second part of the sentence. "How **it** is" is a standard pattern, it's not redundant.

Comment: @Peter Quite so. The two *its* refer to different things.

Comment: Isn't the "it" *always* required? I'm trying to think of a situation where "how is" could ever be correct in this position. In the context, what would "how is" even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two "it"s refer to different things. The first "it" is whatever it is that's doing the showing. The second "it" is a dummy subject used  where grammar requires one but there is no subject.

This is similar to "It is raining" or "Is it time yet?" The "it" provides a subject for a sentence or clause that requires a subject but doesn't have one. It is required.